# Spoof MAC address Win 7 to 00 prefix

Tags: windows-7, mac, router, mac-address, spoofing

I want to change my windows 7 Mac Address of wireless adapter to any adres with a prefix of 00. This because the router i`m on only allows connections of 00-Mac addresses. At least, that is what I think, because any PC that is able to connect has a Mac address starting with 00. And I cannot change this in the router.

After some research I discovered that Windows 7 only allows several prefixes (XA, X2, and a few more of that I know). Is there any way to bypass this restriction?

Comment: What do you mean when you say Windows 7 only allows several prefixes? Are you saying that Windows 7 only allows certain MAC address prefixes? If so the MAC address is tied to the NIC not Windows 7

Comment: No, Windows is not limited to any prefixes.  The first series of digits are a manufacturer identifier though.  So there are a few major ones (Realtek, Broadcom, etc.).  That might be the confusion.

Comment: @user1281146 - Spoofing the MAC address isn't going to fix the actual problem you have. Doing this requires you modify the register which isn't something you should do if your asking how to spoof your mac address.

Comment: Thanks, I have to admit i`m not an expert on MAC adresses, or wireless connections, but to be clear: I know what spoofing is, and I know how to change my MAC address in the register, actually, I did that a few times. But the thins is, changing in the register works with any mac adress starting with x2 or xA, but starting 00 just won`t work (it changes in register, but it does not actually change in my ipconfig)

Comment: And according to some site (I can`t find it now) Windows 7 only allows serveral prefixes. But you say that this has nothing to do with Win 7, but with the manufacturer?

Comment: @user1281146 - The "some" site is wrong.

Comment: Is your router set to only allow certain PC's onto the network? This is usually set when someone logs into the router and specifies SPECIFIC mac addresses. So I am surprised that it will only allow MACs with certain "prefixes". Usually a whole MAC address is specified for access. But that is if that security feature is active to begin with.

Comment: Also, the "prefix" or first 3 parts of a MAC Address usually identifies the manufacturer of the device, not sure if there is any method to the madness of the last 3 parts. http://wiki.answers.com/Q/The_two_parts_of_MAC_addresses

Answer (score 0):

Since no one else bother to post an answer, try [SMAC MAC Adress Changer](http://download.cnet.com/SMAC-MAC-Address-Changer/3000-2085_4-10536535.html) - I have used it in the past, and it worked for me, although I am not sure about giving it a 00-prefix - it probably can, though.

Comment: Thanks ekaj, I did already try SMAC, didn`t work with the 00 prefix (02, or 0A works fine though), guess the only option is to get into the router..

Comment: Ah, sorry that didn't work. I'll leave it here in case it works for someone else in the future.

Answer (score 0):

change adapter settings | right click adapter -> properties | configure | network address

Answer (score 0):

You're entirely right, windows will not allow you to spoof the mac address on wireless cards to anything that does not start with a few certain values. Try going back to an earlier version of you card's driver, or, if that doesn't work, switch to xp or linux, as the restrictions weren't implemented until windows vista.